# Wpf webbrowser load html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have this function in my JavaScript function:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var url = 'url';
    xhr.open('GET', url, false);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            var str = xhr.responseText;
            alert(str);

            var resp = JSON.parse(str);
            alert('12');
            if (0 == resp.ErrorCode) {
                alert('13');
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
```

The str is always :

```
{"ErrorCode":0,"ErrorMessage":"OK","Command":"/api/getvideoinfo/","data":[{"VideoID":"ehcVomMexkY","IsInCache":true,"IsDownloading":false,"AvailableFormats":[{"DisplayName":"720","IsHD":true,"VidEncMimeType":"video/H264","AudEndMimeType":"audio/aac","Width":1280,"Height":720,"PlaybackURL":"","IsDefaultStream":false},{"DisplayName":"360","IsHD":false,"VidEncMimeType":"video/H264","AudEndMimeType":"audio/aac","Width":640,"Height":360,"PlaybackURL":"url","IsDefaultStream":true}]}]}
```

And i noticed that the script never get to :

`alert('12');`

Any idea what can cause this?Why the json won't parse? did i need to add any library to the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `url` is the location of the file on the server. So the `url` variable should be the path from where you get the data which in this case should be

```
var url = "/api/getvideoinfo/";
```